# Check total file size of a specific directory for a specific user

Tags: linux, command, filesize

I want to check how much of the total file storage for a specific user has been used on a specific directory. I am using `ls -lR ./* | grep userid` to list files belonging to a specific user. But then how I can get the total file sizes of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use awk

```
ls -lR ./* | grep userid | awk '{sum = sum + $5} END {print sum}'
```

Comment: anyway to get this "human-readable" on the other side? thanks!

Comment: @shootingstars Simple version producing human-readable output is `ls -lR ./* | grep userid | awk '{sum = sum + $5} END {printf "%iK\n", sum/1024}'`. Because this is integer math, there is no rounding. You could extend this to MB or GB, but anything more complex than this and I would use Ruby.

Answer (score 9):

You can do something like this, which will show you the size if each directory in the users home directory, and will print a total size of their home directory at the end (sum of all sub-directories).

```
du -sch /home/USER/*
```

Comment: but this one doesn't meet my requirement. We have a group directory which all group members can write to and I want to check how much storage space a specific user has used. Not just their home directory. Thanks anyway.